# Add a data from a list/str [not sure/confused] to a Json with some manipulation

Tags: python, json

My data is stored in a variable alldata im not sure if its a list or an str, visual studio code shows it as an str but when i try to do json.loads(alldata) it give an error `Exception: TypeError: reponse is expected to be either of str, bytes, or bytearray, got list`. It is shown as :

```
[{"STATIONS_ID":"44","Date":1356998400000,"Quality_Level":3,"Air_Temperature":8.4,"Relative_Humidity":91.0},{"STATIONS_ID":"44","Date":1357002000000,"Quality_Level":3,"Air_Temperature":8.3,"Relative_Humidity":93.0}]
```

This format does not seem like a valid json format. My desired output as a json should look like :

```
{
"temperatures": alldata,
"station": { "id": station.id }
}
```

Where all data is manipulated and the first field i.e STATIONS_ID is deleted from every field in alldata and only pasted one time in the desired output. And finally return this by
`return func.HttpResponse(alldata, mimetype='application/json')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `alldata` is type `list` or `dict`, you should do serialization, using `json.dumps(alldata)`

If your `alldata` variable is `str` type, you should do deserialization, using `json.loads(alldata)`

`alldata` variable type can be checked by `isinstance(alldata, (list, dict))` or if you just debugging by `type(alldata)`

UPD:
to get desired data format:

```
alldata = [{"STATIONS_ID":"44","Date":1356998400000,"Quality_Level":3,"Air_Temperature":8.4,"Relative_Humidity":91.0},{"STATIONS_ID":"44","Date":1357002000000,"Quality_Level":3,"Air_Temperature":8.3,"Relative_Humidity":93.0}]

desired = [{"temperatures": [{k: v for k, v in x.items() if k != "STATIONS_ID"}], "station": {"id": x["STATIONS_ID"]}} for x in alldata]
print(desired)
```

Result will be like:

```
[{'temperatures': [{'Date': 1356998400000,
    'Quality_Level': 3,
    'Air_Temperature': 8.4,
    'Relative_Humidity': 91.0}],
  'station': {'id': '44'}},
 {'temperatures': [{'Date': 1357002000000,
    'Quality_Level': 3,
    'Air_Temperature': 8.3,
    'Relative_Humidity': 93.0}],
  'station': {'id': '44'}}]
```

Comment: doing json.dumps() on the all data results in something like : ```[{\"STATIONS_ID\":\"44\",\"Date\":1356998400000,\"Quality_Level\":3,\"Air_Temperature\":8.4,\"Relative_Humidity\":91.0}, . . .```

Comment: @snoogybunny you should check out the type of variable before manipulating with it :)

Comment: @snoogybunny maybe alldata is already a string, then you just have pass it without `json.loads()`: `func.HttpResponse(alldata, mimetype='application/json')`

Comment: Yes I am using Azure Functions for this application

Comment: what does `print(type(alldata))` say?

Comment: results in : <class 'str'>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202878/discussion-between-py-dude-and-snoogybunny).